# Custom sorting of 2 LinkedLists of user defined objects based on the class variable in Java

Tags: java, sorting, object, linked-list

I am having two LinkedLists : newLinkedList and oldLinkedList, both contain  BID class objects. Below is my BID class:

```
    public class Bid {

    private int quantity;
    private double bidPrice;

   public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public double getBidprice() {
        return bidPrice;
    }

    public void setBidprice(double bidPrice) {
        this.bidPrice = bidPrice;
    }
}
```

Now I have to create a new LinkedListlist that contains sorted elements of  newLinkedList and oldLinkedList based on price variable of the BID class.
If I get the same price in both the LinkedList then I have to keep newLinkedList BID class object and remove the old one.

That means new LinkedList must contain Bid class objects sorted on the basis of the price variable.

This is my main function:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter size of linkedlist 1 ");
    int size1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter size of linkedlist 2 ");
    int size2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    LinkedList<Bid> oldLinkedList= addElementsToList(size1);
    LinkedList<Bid> newLinkedList= addElementsToList(size2);

    /*
          SORT BOTH THE LINKED LISTS HERE
    */

}

public static LinkedList<Bid> addElementsToList(int size) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    LinkedList<Bid> bidList = new LinkedList<Bid>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Bid bid = new Bid();
        System.out.println("Enter bid price of Object " + i);
        bid.setBidprice(Double.parseDouble(br.readLine()));
        System.out.println("Enter bid quantity of Object " + i);
        bid.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
        bidList.add(bid);
    }
  return bidList;
}
```

Comment: you have two linked list.. then use nested for loop, comparator or anything like

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "Merge two linked lists into one and sort the final list." But the LinkedList contains "Bid" class objects. So the sorting must be done on the basis of the price variable of the "Bid" class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what your want, for each Bid in oldList, check if it's price already exists in newList. If exists, do nothing, otherwise add it to newList, and sort the last newList. You can test it.

Note: I'm not sure if you really want to compare two double price.

```
    boolean containsSamePrice(LinkedList<Bid> list, double price) {
        for (Bid bid : list) {
            if (bid.getBidprice() == price) {
                return true;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }

LinkedList<Bid> mergeAndSort(LinkedList<Bid> newLinkedList, LinkedList<Bid> oldLinkedList) {
    for (Bid oldBid : oldLinkedList) {
        if (!containsSamePrice(newLinkedList, oldBid.getBidprice())) {
            newLinkedList.add(oldBid);
        }
    }
    Comparator<Bid> comparator = new Comparator<Bid>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Bid o1, Bid o2) {
            if (o1.getBidprice() < o2.getBidprice())
                return -1;
            if (o2.getBidprice() == o2.getBidprice())
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(newLinkedList, comparator);
    return newLinkedList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Yes, I want to compare the double prices but there is a small change , if the oldbid.getprice() is equal to any of the price in the newLinkedList then I have to add the newLinkedList Bid object into the Sorted list, but not the oldBid one from the oldLinkedList

Comment: Yes, we can use the newLinkedList as the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the Comparator Interface in Bid class and use a Collections.sort() method.